# SciPy interpolation gives unexpectedly curved line

Tags: python, scipy

For the data set

```
  x   y

  1  80
  4  40
 16  20
 64  10
256   5
```

LibreOffice Calc gives me the following (polynomial, degree 3, Trend Line)

[image: calc]

but `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` called with `kind='cubic'` yields this:

[image]

I've tried playing with `interp1d`'s arguments and also tried spline interpolation and `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` but neither gave me something similar to what Calc produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you did in LibreOffice Calc was transform x to a logarithmic scale and then fit the data to a cubic polynomial. The logarithmic scale is important; fitting to x and y directly results in the wrong curve. This is the Python equivalent:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 4, 16, 64, 256]
y = [80, 40, 20, 10, 5]
logx = np.log2(x)
plt.scatter(logx, y, marker='s')
plt.xticks(logx, x)
plt.grid()

coeff = np.polyfit(logx, y, 3)
yfit = np.poly1d(coeff)

logx_new = np.linspace(logx[0], logx[-1], 100)
plt.plot(logx_new, yfit(logx_new))
```

`interp1d` does spline interpolation, which in the case of a cubic spline fits every 3 adjacent points to a cubic polynomial. It's different from fitting all the data to a cubic polynomial, whether you transform x or not.

Comment: So I was looking for a function `f` for which `f(x) = y` but instead found a function `g` for which `g(log(x)) = y`. Is there a way to compute `f` directly?

Comment: The math gives you a hint. `f(x) = y = g(log(x))`. So in Python code, `def f(x): return g(np.log2(x))`

Comment: I mean if I print what you called `coeff` or `yfit` I can immediately see the formula of `g`. But can I obtain the formula of `f` either from `g` or directly?

Comment: Oh I see you mean the f(x) in your figure. I'm not sure that you do want that. I hardcoded the formula into a Python function and tried `[f(i) for i in x]`. `f(1)` is close to the correct 80, but the rest are completely off.